# mac scrollbar ruins css layout alignment

Tags: html, css, macos

I am Mac OS user and I found something weird.

This is the example code.

```css
header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  
}

.wrapper{
  max-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto; /* to make align center */
}

main {
  max-width: 500px; /* same as .wrapper */
  width: 100%;
  height: 120vh; /* to make scrollbar */
  margin: auto; /* to make align center */
  padding-top: 58px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">123</div>
</header>
<main>main</main>
```

[image]

You can see the gap between header and main.

[image]

But I go to `System Preferences` of Mac, click the `General` and change `Show scroll bars` option to `When scrolling`, it shows well like below picture.

[image]

How can I align the layout of header and main even if I set the `Show scroll bars` option `always`?

- List item

Comment: Probably an issue with `100vw` vs `100%`. Try and remove `width` from the `header` styles, and add `right: 0` instead.

Comment: @CBroe has a point.  The header is set to 100vw where as the main is set to 100%. Viewport width includes the scrollbar where as 100% makes it the width of its containing element.  In this case that is the document body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following code. I have placed comments in the CSS

```css
* {
  /* all elements are now border box */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /* changed from 100vw to 100% */
  width: 100%;
  height: 58px;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  /* aligns wrapper element to the center of the header no matter its contents height */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrapper {
  /* use  width or min width because contents may not be 500px wide */
  min-width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

main {
  /* use max width because you dont want your main element wider than 500px */
  max-width: 500px;
  /* to make scrollbar */
  height: 120vh;
  /* 0 margin on top and bottom and auto for left and right */
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 58px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="wrapper">123</div>
</header>
<main>main</main>
```